# How to set hidden/operating system files visibility for specific folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Apart from my desktop folder view, I want to see hidden files and protected system files in every other folder on my computer - is there any way to remove `thumbs.db` and `desktop.ini` in particular from my desktop ONLY, while still leaving similar files visible in other folders?

I know I can delete the `.ini` files without too much trouble, but `thumbs.db` will keep coming back every time I move an image file onto my desktop, right? Please tell me there's some sort of super secret "don't show files matching this regex" in the registry somewhere.

Note - "there's no way to do that" is a viable (though regrettable) answer too - I've been searching around a bit and other people have asked the same question, with about as much luck as I've been having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the option for showing hidden folders/files is a global setting in Windows Explorer, I'm afraid that we can't do that (I say "we" because I would like to get rid of the two "desktop.ini" files of the Desktop).

Also, I don't think that this is going to change in a while, since it's a feature that will be useful only for a minor part of users (since almost all "regular" users have hidden files, well, hidden, and for better), and it's not trivial to implement it.

From [Minus 100 points](https://web.archive.org/web/20160229162228/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) (this talks about .NET but is applicable to Windows development as other [MS bloggers have noted](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090928-00/?p=16573)):

> So, we decided on the additive
> approach instead, and worked hard to
> keep the complexity down. One way to
> do that is through the concept of
> “minus 100 points”. Every feature
> starts out in the hole by 100 points,
> which means that it has to have a
> significant net positive effect on the
> overall package for it to make it into
> the language. Some features are okay
> features for a language to have, they
> just aren't quite good enough to make
> it into the language.